# Over-the-Counter Drug: "senpreskriba" or "ekstermenda" medikamento?

Tags: single-word-requests

Which is more appropriate for "over-the-counter drug"?

A. senpreskriba medikamento
B. ekstermenda medikamento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *senpreskriba medikamento* is an accurate translation. *Ekstermenda medikamento* I understand as a drug that ought to be destroyed (eksterm-end-a).

Comment: Thanks. Quite appreciated.

Would you say that 'ekstermenda' includes expired drugs (passed their 'best before date')?